# Struggling to grasp Recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Right now I'm going through Codecademy's recursion track and I'm confused how to interpret this correct code.

```
// Create an empty array called "stack"
var stack = []
// Here is our recursive function
function power(base, exponent) {
  // Base case 
  if ( exponent === 0 ) {
    return 1;
  }
  // Recursive case
  else {
    stack[exponent-1] = base * power(base, exponent - 1); //confused by start of this line
    return stack[exponent-1];
  }
}
power(3,3)
console.log(stack) // [3,9,27]
```

If exponent-1 becomes 2 then 1 then 0, why does 3 become the element at the 0th position in the array rather than at the 2nd position (and so on) ?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Because the first result is the highest, it's assigning the array positions backwards. So the first one would be `stack[2] = 27`, which places the 27  in the 3rd position of the array.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm asking because I had written console.log(stack) before the return statement and it gave me outputs of [3] [3,9] and [3,9,27] respectively. How would that make sense if it initially computes the 2nd position of the array?

Comment: Because of the recursion, you'll have the deepest ( `[3]` ) returned first. It then continues returning up the stack.

Comment: Think I've got it. So basically it does all the calculation until it has a clear value w/o a recursive call, in this case 3. Then it is able to do the calculations for the subsequent positions in the array. Is that correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup! @Bergi 's answer has an excellent breakdown of the logic.

Answer (score 2):

On the first pass, exponent is 3, so you will store a value at stack[2].  But that value is not calculated until the recursive call has completed with power(3,2)...power(3, 1).

So the assignment to stack[3-1] is preceded by the one to stack [3-2], which in turn is preceded by the one to stack[3-2]

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there are four different exponents in the execution of this call, one in each scope of the `power` invocation.

```
call power(3, 3)
    exponent' = 3
    is not 0
    calls power(3, 2)
        exponent'' = 2
        is not 0
        calls power(3, 1)
            exponent''' = 1
            is not 0
            calls power(3, 0)
                exponent'''' = 0
                is 0
                returns 1
            multiplies the return value by 3
            assigns it to stack[exponent'''-1]: stack[0] = 3
            returns 3
        multiplies the return value by 3
        assigns it to stack[exponent''-1]: stack[1] = 9
        returns 9
    multiplies the return value by 3
    asigns it to stack[exponent'-1]: stack[2] = 27
    returns 27
logs the value of stack
```

Indeed the stack is built "backwards", after returning from the recursive calls, not before entering them. If you want to have a better representation of the call stack, you can try to add

```
callstack.push(exponent);
```

in the first line of your function body. After the execution of your script, the `callstack` would look like `[3, 2, 1, 0]` as you might have expected.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Think I'm getting it. So once 1 is returned that's not added to the array b/c exponent -1 would equal stack[-1]. Then power (3,1) can be calculated because it equals 3 * power(3,0) which is returned as 1 and 3 * 1 is 3. And stack[1-1] = 0. Then power(3,2) can run b/c its 3 * power(3,1) which we now know is 3. So 3 * 3 is 9 and stack[2-1] = 1 etc. I guess it just clicked for me while typing this. Thanks.

Comment: @Gwater17: Yes, basically.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you write it out in a table:

```
power(3, 3)   stack[2] = 3 * power(3, 2)
power(3, 2)   stack[1] = 3 * power(3, 1)
power(3, 1)   stack[0] = 3 * power(3, 0)
power(3, 0)   return 1
```

Then substitute the values:

```
stack[0] = 3 * 1
stack[1] = 3 * 3
stack[2] = 3 * 9
```